# Ransack: Undefined method name in filter active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

I am having a problem with active admin filter. I am getting the following issue,

```
undefined method `affiliate_link_of_affiliate_id_eq' for #<Ransack::Search:0x00007f80ef1078f0>
```

and i have used this filter query in `admin/affiliate_session.rb`

```
filter :affiliate_link_of_affiliate_id_eq, as: :select, collection: -> { Affiliate.all}, label: 'Affiliate'
```

so my question here is that I want to filter the sessions with affiliates.
What should be the correct method name to do so that i can filter the session with affiliates in active admin.

My models are

```
affilate.rb

class Affiliate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :links
end

link.rb
class Affiliate::Link < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sessions, foreign_key: 'affiliate_link_id'
  belongs_to :affiliate
end

session.rb
class Affiliate::Session < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :link, foreign_key: 'affiliate_link_id'
end
```

EDIT:

The above error resolved by using this `link_of_Affiliate_type_id_eq` in method and all Affiliates are there in dropdown but when i select anyone it doesn't give any sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use `ransackable_attributes` in your model ?
For instance

```
def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
  ['affiliate_link_id']
end
```